# What is the relationship between keyedStream and Table API?

Tags: apache-flink

As far as I know, `DataStream` and `KeyedDataStream` are abstraction of flink data stream. `KeyedDataStream` means that data are partitioned by key so that data with the same key are on the same machine.

Code looks something like:

```
KeyedDatastream keyedStream = datastream.keyBy(foo)
```

On the other hand, We can do similar thing on the DataStream if we register it as a table by flink Table API. Code looks something like:

```
Table table = table.groupBy(foo)
```

When using table API, it returns a `KeyedDataStream` Object but not a `Table` Object.
Does it mean that flink itself knows how to handle `groupBy`  operation and still process logic based on the key of data, and data with the same key is process on the same machine just as Stream API does?

Answer (score 1):

Some GROUP BY operations are understood by Flink's SQL planner as being used to describe windowing -- in which case they are not implemented as keyed partitioning of the underlying datastreams. But otherwise, yes, most uses of GROUP BY are implemented as a `keyBy`.